# Is this plot supposed to look this way?

Tags: matlab

[image]

We have this Continuous signal:

```
x(t)=cos(100*pi*t)+cos(200*pi*t)+sin(500*pi*t)
```

and what we need to do is sample it and then reconstruct it. We made it in Matlab but it looks like a box and we are wondering if this is how it was supposed to look.

```matlab
x = @(t) cos(100*pi*t)+cos(200*pi*t)+sin(500*pi*t);
t = -10:1/1000:10;
figure(1);
plot(t, x(t));
grid;
```

Answer (score 1):

I recreated the plot on my MATLAB, and yes I saw the same "box" behavior. Notably, graphing the function on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com) with this domain of `[-10 10]` also showed a similar "box".

I believe that the problem is originating from your choice of the domain (`[-10 10]`) which is causing the function to appear as a "box". For example, resizing to the following domain (`[-0.05 0.05]`)

```
t = -0.05: 1/10000: 0.05;
```

produces this clearer plot:

[image: plot produced with x domain of -0.05 to 0.05, the function no longer appears as a box and can be more clearly viewed]